# Was ist die Grundbedeutung des Verbes „kündigen“?

Tags: verb

Ich habe viele Verben mit *kündigen* gesehen. Beispielsweise:

> ankündigen, kündigen, aufkündigen, erkundigen, verkündigen

Aber diese Verben haben keine einander ähnliche Bedeutung, ich verstehe die Beziehung zwischen diesen Verben nicht (obwohl sie das gleiche Grundwort benutzen). Wie ist die zugrundeliegende Bedeutung, von der sich diese Verben ableiten?

Comment: Ich frage mich, woher _unterstreichend_ rührt. _Underlining_ statt _underlying_ möglicherweise?

Comment: Sie haben Recht. Ist das nicht richtig oder? Ich habe "underlying" gemeint.

Comment: Nein, ist dann nicht richtig. _Underlying_ = _zugrundeliegend_; dagegen meint das andere Wort _underline_.

Comment: In *erkundigen* sehe ich aber kein *kündigen*. Wohl aber stammt es auch von *Kunde* ab.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar - war ursprünglich als "erkündigen" in der Frage. Ich finde, man kann das einfach so stehenlassen, zumal es schließlich zu der Gruppe dazugehört.

Comment: @Stephie Ich war nur verwundert, weil es um Verben mit "kündigen" ging und dann "erkundigen" drinstand in der Liste. Ich sagte ja auch, dass "erkundigen" ebenfalls von "Kunde" abstammt (also "die Kunde", nicht "der Kunde") und von daher dennoch reinpasst.

Comment: @chirlu haben das folgende Adjektiv in dict.cc gesucht und dict.cc gibt mir seine Bedeutung als "underlying". Auf jeden Fall bedanken ich mich bei Ihnen.

Comment: Tatsächlich. Offenbar ein Fehler in dict.cc; ich habe einen Korrekturhinweis geschickt.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Alle gehen zurück auf *[die Kunde](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Kunde_Botschaft_Nachricht)*, was so viel wie *Botschaft, Nachricht, Information oder Wissen* bedeutet (mehr dazu unter dem Link oben).

Deine Verben beschäftigen sich alle mit der "Verarbeitung" oder "Verlautbarung" derartiger Information:

- ankündigen:
  etwas Kommendes bekanntmachen
- kündigen und aufkündigen:
  das Ende einer Vereinbarung oder Verbindung erklären
- erkundigen:
  sich im eine Information bemühen
- verkünden / verkündigen:
  eine Information oder Botschaft bekanntmachen

Comment: Ich verstehe jetzt, warum diese Verben unterschiedliche Bedeutungen haben. Vielen Dank.